# Converting JSON data into a ColdFusion struct

Tags: arrays, json, web-services, coldfusion

The following code I have works like a treat. It is taking data from my SQL database table and outputting it into the structure below within a cfc, the output is called from my mobile app, and the code works as required.

```
<cfset currentRow=1>    
<cfloop query="LT_Customers">

<cfset tempData = structNew()>
<cfset tempData["imei"] = LT_Customers.imei[currentRow]>
<cfset tempData["id"] = LT_Customers.id[currentRow]>
<cfset tempData["name"] = LT_Customers.last_name[currentRow]>
<cfset tempData["model"] = LT_Customers.Model[currentRow]>
<cfset tempData["trackee"] = LT_Customers.trackee[currentRow]>
<cfset tempData["mobile"] = LT_Customers.mobile[currentRow]>
<cfset tempData["app_user_mobile"] = LT_Customers.app_user_mobile[currentRow]>
<cfset arrayAppend(result, tempData)> 
<cfset currentRow=currentRow+1>
</cfloop>
<cfreturn result>
</cffunction>
```

I now have data coming from a webservice that is returned to my page in JSON format. All I want to do is replicate the above so that my cfc function can output the JSON data in the exact same way as shown above. The webservice outputs data as below

```
<cfhttp url="http://api.sensis.com.au/v1/test/search?key=czsjp3f8xhd835vg6xfw8ber&query=vetinary%20and%20clinic&radius=1&location=-37.7833,144.9667" method="get" result="httpResp" timeout="120">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
</cfhttp>

<cfset Data=DeserializeJSON(httpResp.filecontent)>

<cfdump var="#Data#">
```

Having spent many hours researching how to achieve the above I need to concede that I need assistance from those far more experienced them myself. I just need to be able to generate the same structure I have using the JSON content as I have with the sql query (yes I appreciate the column names are different)

I thank you in advance for any assistance that can be provided.

Comment: What is your final goal? Seems like you're taking a pretty roundabout way to output a query.

Comment: Hi Matt, the final goal is to be able to output the data from the webservice just as i have from the query example. I have written an iphone app that calls the cfc and the cfc returns the data in the structure shown in the inital example, the app page then processes the data and displays it in a list on the app page. I am happy with the way the example query works and the output it generates for my app, i simply need to get the same structure outputted from the json data

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the results to build your structure.

```
<cfloop array="#data.results#" index="x">

 // build your results array in here...

 <cfset tempData = structNew()>
 <cfset tempData["imei"] = x.whatever>
 <cfset tempData["id"] = x.whatever>
 <cfset tempData["name"] = x.whatever>
 <cfset tempData["model"] = x.whatever>
 <cfset tempData["trackee"] = x.whatever>
 <cfset tempData["mobile"] = x.whatever>
 <cfset tempData["app_user_mobile"] = x.whatever>
 <cfset arrayAppend(result, Duplicate(tempData))> 

</cfloop>
```

Comment: Hi Slick 
 i followed your steps and yes its now outputting however the output is repeating the same record for the total number of records rather than displaying the details of the next record in the data set ??   i welcome your thoughts

Comment: try my amended example. Using Duplicate()

Comment: SlickRick - Good thought, but it should be not be necessary. The loop code creates a new structure on each iteration, so it is not ["passed by reference"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7617372/104223) problem.  user3288814 - That suggests something different in your code. When you say "output" do you mean the raw *result* of the function (ie dumping the `result` variable shows duplicate values) - or when you display the results on some other page? Can you please update your question with your current code AND a sample of the actual JSON received from the web service (obfuscate it if needed).

Comment: *so it is not "passed by reference" problem* Not unless you are dealing with complex values. However, without a sample of the desired format and received JSON string it is difficult to answer that question.

Comment: You are right Leigh - the only way I could replicate the problem was to remove the structNew() line. The code provided in the question returns the JSON packet.